# Debugging exceptions in type initializers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a static class with no static constructor, but many static members.  I throw a TypeInitializationException when the class is first used.

I am breaking on CLR exceptions, and I have disabled 'Just My Code'.

The problem is that I only get this exception when this class is first used; I don't break at the failing static field initializer.  I could certainly remove the static members until I find the culprit, but is there an easier way?

Does anyone have any tips for debugging static field initializations?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Click Debug, Exceptions, (or press Ctrl+D, E) and tell Visual Studio to break whenever any exception is thrown.  It will then break when the InnerException is thrown, before it gets wrapped in a TypeInitializationException, and it will break on the line that threw the exception.

Alternatively, look at the InnerException's call stack and see which of your field s it matches.

Or, try setting a breakpoint on every static initializer; the last one hit is the one that threw the exception.

Comment: How have I never known about this?

Comment: This doesn't work for me (VS2010, .Net4). But I can see the inner exception details. I think the reason is that I am instantiating a type using Assembly.CreateInstance().

Comment: *UPDATE* I can hit the breakpoint now if I *disable* 'break on throw' and disable 'just my code'.

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following

- Disable Just My Code: Uncheck Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Just my Code
- Break on first chance exceptions: Debug -> Exception -> Check the thrown box for CLR exceptions

This should take you to the immediate place where the exception is occurring.