# AndroidApp and MySqlConnection didn't work connection.open

Tags: c#, android, mysql, xamarin.android, i18next

When I try to open the connection  an error occurred and say:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception.

This is the part of code:

```
MySqlConnection _Conn;

public void Conectar()
{
    new I18N.West.CP1250();

    string SC;

    SC = "server = XXX; Port = 3306; database = XXX; user id = XXX; password = XXX; charset = utf8";

    _Conn = new MySqlConnection(SC);

    _Conn.Open();
}
```

Comment: This exception usually means that the static constructor for `ReplicationManager` threw an exception. Without the full exception message and callstack from _that_ exception, we're unlikely to be able to help you. It would also be helpful to know which version of MySql.Data you're using.

Comment: I dunno how to show you the full exception message and callstack from the exception. Can you pls say to me how to do that?

Comment: Try looking for other Stack Overflow answers on how to debug a TypeInitializationException, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604352

Comment: This is the exception:
"System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.\n

Comment: Which version of MySql.Data are you using?

Comment: I am actually using the 8.0.11.0

Comment: It sounds like it's just not compatible with Xamarin Android. You might want to try a different MySQL connector (that has different dependencies) to see if it's compatible with your platform: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Comment: That's work. Thank you so much

Comment: Great! I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: This part of the exception message, and other messages I have received when trying to work with the Oracle MySQL package on Xamarin/Android, means that this library doesn't work with Xamarin/Android due to architecture or OS incompatibilities:
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.

Answer (score 2):

If you problem ocorred with Xamarin, you should do:

1) Remove Reference Mysql Data

2) Add Reference Xamarin.Mysql

You can keep yours calls (using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;)

Comment: This also solves the '...no constructor...' exception at initialization.  Only now (2019-10-13, Studio 2017), the package is just called "MySqlConnector".  Thanks, Dennis!

Comment: Xamarin.Mysql is not available by default, I think you have installed any other NuGet packages that creates that library and that allow you to use it, but it is not native or included with Xamarin. If you could confirm which library are you using in order to use and test that reference, or where to download it would be great.

Answer (score 2):

***SOLVED***

Use package Nuget ***MySqlConnector*** instead of MySql.Data

***I'm using it and it's ok on Xamarin Android***

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Bye

Comment: Any particular reason for the mismatching package names? The one with the dot doesn't seem to exist and a little misguiding imo.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager` static constructor is trying to initialise the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` class, which isn't supported on Xamarin Android.

To avoid this, you could use an alternative MySQL client library that doesn't have that dependency, such as [MySqlConnector on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this Oracle package (https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/), isn't it? Then, this part of the exception message you get:

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
```

Means that **this library doesn't work with Xamarin/Android due to architecture or OS incompatibilities**. There is no compiler errors, but that Oracle MySQL package also raises other exceptions always related to architecture/OS when trying to execute its methods on a Xamarin/Android app, so I recently writed a message to Oracle asking them to include this info about incompatibilities on the README... All forums related to Xamarin and this library ends talking about its Android incompatibility issues.

**Here is the solution I use instead of the Oracle library**. It's an alternative, up to date and very similar (and 100% working in Xamarin Android) package on NuGet, you can get it here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/

Another alternative, very similar, but less updated and used:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.MySql.Data/

*And there is also another package (With all doc in chinese and a weird/sofisticated way to build querys...) but it also works and receives frecuently updates. But better take a look to doc and examples here before trying to use:
https://github.com/dotnetcore/FreeSql*