# MySQL Connection Failing? Error? Xamarin And C#

Tags: c#, mysql, xamarin

So I've been making this login app (on android with xamarin in vis studio 17) for an internship and what I've basically done is make it so when a visitor comes in, they sign in and when pressing the sign in button a page opens, thus having them put in their info and then (the page where they put their info is what I'm going to be posting) it sends their data to the database as well as sending them back to the homepage(where the app starts off at). I can get to the page where it puts all their details and whatnot, but when pressing sign in I get this error:

Below Is My Code: 
For Signing In:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace MRC_Sign_In_Sheet
{
    public class OnSignInEvenArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private string txtName;
        private string txtRepresent;
        private string txtToSee;
        private string txtPurpose;
        private string classification;
        private string citizenStatus;       

        public string Name
        {
            get { return txtName; }
            set { txtName = value; }
        }
        public string Represent
        {
            get { return txtRepresent; }
            set { txtRepresent = value; }
        }
        public string ToSee
        {
            get { return txtToSee; }
            set { txtToSee = value; }
        }
        public string Purpose
        {
            get { return txtPurpose; }
            set { txtPurpose = value; }
        }
        public string CitizenStatus
        {
            get { return citizenStatus; }
            set { citizenStatus = value; }
        }
        public string Classification
        {
            get { return classification; }
            set { classification = value; }
        }

        public OnSignInEvenArgs(string name, string represent, string tosee, string purpose, string citizenstatus, string classification) : base()
        {
            Name = name;
            Represent = represent;
            ToSee = tosee;
            Purpose = purpose;
            CitizenStatus = citizenstatus;
            Classification = classification;
        }
    }

    class SignInDialog : DialogFragment
    {
        Button signInBack;
        RadioButton radCitizen;
        RadioButton radNotCitizen;
        RadioButton radClassified;
        RadioButton radUnclassified;
        private EditText txtName;
        private EditText txtRepresent;
        private EditText txtToSee;
        private EditText txtPurpose;
        private string classification;
        private string citizenStatus;
        public event EventHandler<OnSignInEvenArgs> nOnSignInComplete;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SignIn, container, false);

            txtName = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtName);
            txtRepresent = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtRepresent);
            txtToSee = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtToSee);
            txtPurpose = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtPurpose);
            radCitizen = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radCitizen);
            radNotCitizen = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radNotCitizen);
            radClassified = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radClassified);
            radUnclassified = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radUnclassified);
            signInBack = view.FindViewById<Button>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.signInBack);

            if(radCitizen.Checked)
            {
                citizenStatus = "Citizen";
            }
            else if(radNotCitizen.Checked)
            {
                citizenStatus = "Not A Citizen";
            }
            if(radClassified.Checked)
            {
                classification = "Classified";
            }
            else if (radUnclassified.Checked)
            {
                classification = "Unclassified";
            }
            signInBack.Click += SignIn_Click;           
            return view;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_Animations;
        }

        void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int badgeNum = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
            DateTime dateTimeSignIn = DateTime.Now;


            MySqlConnection con;
            string connectionstring = "Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;Database=mrcwebappdb;User Id=dbeditor;Password=Monster001359%;charset=utf8";
            con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);

            con.Open();                                
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO visitormanagement(visitorName,visitorBadgeNumber,visitorRepresent,visitorToSee,visitorPurpose,visitorCitizenship,visitorClassification,visitorSignIn) VALUES(@visitorName,@visitorBadgeNumber,@visitorRepresent,@visitorToSee,@visitorPurpose,@visitorCitizenship,@visitorClassification,@visitorSignIn)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorName", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorBadgeNumber", badgeNum.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorRepresent", txtRepresent.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorToSee", txtToSee.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorPurpose", txtPurpose.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorCitizenship", citizenStatus);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorVlassification", classification);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@visitorSignIn", dateTimeSignIn.ToString());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            nOnSignInComplete.Invoke(this, new OnSignInEvenArgs(txtName.Text, txtRepresent.Text, txtToSee.Text, txtPurpose.Text, citizenStatus, classification));

            this.Dismiss(); //This brings me back to the home page
        }
    }
}
```

this is the error that I'm currently getting: Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. occurred

btw: I'm using that db4free site just for testing purposes as per the fact that if I was putting it into a locally hosted db, the location would be the specific address of the server. I realize that the error (if I'm not mistaken) has something to do with when the connection is being opened, or I could just straight up be completely and utterly wrong. Any help for this would be greatly appreciated.

Quick Update: So I had realized that I was doing a sort of *expletive* backwards approach to connecting it to the database. Now It connects but when submitting, I get this new error. The Following Below is the code as of now (first is signing in, second is signing out).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using MySqlConnector;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


namespace MRC_Sign_In_Sheet
{   
    class SignInDialog : DialogFragment
    {        
        Button signInBack;
        RadioButton radCitizen;
        RadioButton radNotCitizen;
        RadioButton radClassified;
        RadioButton radUnclassified;
        private EditText txtName;
        private EditText txtRepresent;
        private EditText txtToSee;
        private EditText txtPurpose;
        private string classification;
        private string citizenStatus;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SignIn, container, false);

            txtName = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtName);
            txtRepresent = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtRepresent);
            txtToSee = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtToSee);
            txtPurpose = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.txtPurpose);
            radCitizen = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radCitizen);
            radNotCitizen = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radNotCitizen);
            radClassified = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radClassified);
            radUnclassified = view.FindViewById<RadioButton>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.radUnclassified);
            signInBack = view.FindViewById<Button>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.signInBack);

            if (radCitizen.Checked)
            {
                citizenStatus = "Citizen";
            }
            else if (radNotCitizen.Checked)
            {
                citizenStatus = "Not A Citizen";
            }
            if (radClassified.Checked)
            {
                classification = "Classified";
            }
            else if (radUnclassified.Checked)
            {
                classification = "Unclassified";
            }
            signInBack.Click += SignIn_Click;
            return view;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_Animations;
        }

        void SignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int badgeNum = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
            DateTime dateTimeSignIn = DateTime.Now;

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;Database=mrcwebappdb;Uid=dbeditor;pwd=Monster001359%;");  
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO visitormanagement(visitorName, visitorBadgeNumber, visitorRepresent, visitorToSee, visitorPurpose, visitorCitizenship, visitorClassification, visitorSignIn) VALUES('" + txtName.Text + "','" + badgeNum + "'," + txtRepresent.Text + "','" + txtToSee.Text + "','" + txtPurpose.Text + "','" + citizenStatus + "','" + classification + "','" + dateTimeSignIn + ")";

            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            this.Dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

For Signing Out:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using MySqlConnector;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace MRC_Sign_In_Sheet
{


    class SignOutDialog : DialogFragment
    {
        Button signOutBack;
        private EditText signOutName;
        private EditText signOutBadge;

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SignOut, container, false);

            signOutName = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.signOutName);
            signOutBadge = view.FindViewById<EditText>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.signOutBadge);
            signOutBack = view.FindViewById<Button>(MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.Resource.Id.signOutBack);

            signOutBack.Click += SignOut_Click;

            return view;
        }

        public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.Style.dialog_Animations;
        }

        void SignOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs a)
        {
            DateTime dateTimeSignOut = DateTime.Now;

            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;Database=mrcwebappdb;Uid=dbeditor;pwd=Monster001359%;");
            string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO visitormanagementsignout(visitorName, visitorBadgeNumber, visitorSignOutTime) VALUES('" + signOutName.Text + "','" + signOutBadge + "'," + dateTimeSignOut + ")";

            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            this.Dismiss();
        }   
    }
}
```

Im getting this in the output
"Unhandled Exception:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred." with no more information after that. I looked in the debug and this is a collection of my sign in and sign out that appeared. Below is the debug for both where the error occurs.

```
On Sign In
-----------------------------------------------------
Unhandled Exception:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

05-21 17:52:39.623 D/Mono    (12745): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf8223678] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xf8222e88]: 2
05-21 17:52:39.623 D/Mono    (12745): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
05-21 17:52:39.623 D/Mono    (12745): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf8223678] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
05-21 17:52:39.624 D/Mono    (12745): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.MRC_Sign_In_Sheet-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-21 17:52:39.625 D/Mono    (12745): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.MRC_Sign_In_Sheet-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-21 17:52:39.625 D/Mono    (12745): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
05-21 17:52:39.625 D/Mono    (12745): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
05-21 17:52:39.626 D/Mono    (12745): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xf7a39d78] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf8223678]: 2
05-21 17:52:39.626 D/Mono    (12745): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf8223678] -> mscorlib[0xf79f65c8]: 23
05-21 17:52:43.443 I/Kernel  (12745): [303182.603650] <0> (0)[12801:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc0290649c0, buf=ffffffc0049b2800, ref=4, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:52:43.443 I/Kernel  (12745): [303182.603679] <0> (0)[12801:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc003519f80, buf=ffffffc038f00500, ref=2, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:52:43.443 I/Kernel  (12745): [303182.603696] <0> (0)[12801:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc02f609540, buf=ffffffc039616000, ref=4, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:52:43.443 I/Kernel  (12745): [303182.603741] <0> (0)[12801:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc03a96f080, buf=ffffffc039616e00, ref=2, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:52:43.443 I/Kernel  (12745): [303182.603757] <0> (0)[12801:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc029064c00, buf=ffffffc03b5b2b00, ref=8, size=3833856, kmap=0

______________________________________________________
On Sign Out
------------------------------------------------------
Unhandled Exception:

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

05-21 17:51:25.292 D/Mono    (12603): Image addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf81e7578] -> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll[0xf8213c30]: 2
05-21 17:51:25.292 D/Mono    (12603): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization' (System.Runtime.Serialization.dll)
05-21 17:51:25.292 D/Mono    (12603): Assembly System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf81e7578] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
05-21 17:51:25.293 D/Mono    (12603): AOT: image 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.MRC_Sign_In_Sheet-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-21 17:51:25.294 D/Mono    (12603): AOT: image '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MRC_Sign_In_Sheet.MRC_Sign_In_Sheet-1/lib/arm/libaot-System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.so" not found
05-21 17:51:25.294 D/Mono    (12603): Config attempting to parse: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.config'.
05-21 17:51:25.294 D/Mono    (12603): Config attempting to parse: '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Serialization/System.Runtime.Serialization.config'.
05-21 17:51:25.294 D/Mono    (12603): Assembly Ref addref Mono.Android[0xf7a39ac0] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf81e7578]: 2
05-21 17:51:25.295 D/Mono    (12603): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xf81e7578] -> mscorlib[0xf79f6318]: 23
Loaded assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
05-21 17:51:31.753 I/Kernel  (12603): [303110.913251] <0> (0)[12665:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc01c34b080, buf=ffffffc02ec3ad00, ref=4, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:51:31.753 I/Kernel  (12603): [303110.913288] <0> (0)[12665:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc031b94400, buf=ffffffc03703e600, ref=4, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:51:31.753 I/Kernel  (12603): [303110.913313] <0> (0)[12665:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc046020d00, buf=ffffffc0370c2a00, ref=2, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:51:31.753 I/Kernel  (12603): [303110.913339] <0> (0)[12665:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc046020840, buf=ffffffc0370c2c00, ref=2, size=3891200, kmap=0
05-21 17:51:31.753 I/Kernel  (12603): [303110.913364] <0> (0)[12665:Timer-Scheduler][name:ion&][ION]warning: release handle @ client destroy: handle=ffffffc01c1f47c0, buf=ffffffc03b5b2b00, ref=8, size=3833856, kmap=0
```

What in the world is causing this?

Comment: Googling for `System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception. occurred` shows a number of promising results. If you could update your post with which of those solutions you have tried that would be super helpful.

Comment: The `MySql.Data` library isn't supported on Android; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137205/androidapp-and-mysqlconnection-didnt-work-connection-open/50354463#50354463

Comment: @BradleyGrainger so I had changed some things and got your library. Now I'm getting the errors for my updated post. Any help on this or thoughts would be greatly appreciated my friend.

Comment: @DiabolicNick Sorry, I'm not sure what's wrong at this point. Being able to see the `InnerExceptions` of the `AggregateException` might help track it down further.