# Is there a way to fix Xamarin Forms Android 'Configuration system failed to initialize' when device / emulator loads data

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to display data that is fetched from database, MySQL. However, this error is persistently showing when run and the emulator forcely close itself with a message of: `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'`

Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
    public IList<user> users { get; set; }

    public TimeMonitoring()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class user 
    { 
        public string user_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var koneksi = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Resources.db_con);
        koneksi.Open(); // It is directing to this error 
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from users", koneksi); // It is directing to this error 
        var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        users = new List<user>();

        while(rd.Read())
        {
                users.Add(new user
                {
                    user_name = rd.GetString("user_name"), 
                    email = rd.GetString("email"),
                }
            );
        }
        rd.Close();
        listview_users.ItemsSource = users;

        koneksi.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Try to Delete this line ```listview_users.ItemsSource = users;``` and bind it to the xaml instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [MySqlConnector NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/). There are [reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50137205/androidapp-and-mysqlconnection-didnt-work-connection-open) of the error you mention when using MySql.Data.

The System.Configuration stuff is mostly not available on Xamarin. This is a hint you may be using a version not made for Xamarin.

Comment: I already did, it solved the problem